# Call spring bean from MEL with MuleMessage parameter

Tags: java, spring, mule

I'm looking for a way to call a spring bean from Mule's MEL, and pass in the MuleMessage.

I'm specifically looking for the `exceptionPayload` property of the message, as i'm calling from a choice exception handler. I've tried calling the bean like this:

```
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[app.registry.myBean.aMethod(message)]" doc:name="Choice 1">
            <set-payload value="blah" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
```

...but, the parameter passed is `org.mule.el.context.MessageContext` which has no access to the message or any exception properties.

Comment: have you tried with the variable exception, normally contains the exception info at least when you are already in the exception block.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind tying yourself into the Mule API, which is not really an issue as you want to use Mule specifics anyway. I would either write a custom message processor implementing https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/processor/MessageProcessor.html

Or implementing Callable:https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/Callable.html

Both allow you to drill down into the Message.

Or alternatively make your spring bean non-mule specific and just pass the exception and the variables to the method separately.